# Continuous map between closed unit square and closed disc

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

We consider the closed unit square of length 1 with two of it's vertices at $(0,0) $ and $(1,1)$ and the closed disc of radius 2 with center at $(0,0)$. Is there any way to show that there exists a continuous map between these two objects without explicitly constructing a map? This is from a real analysis textbook, so I'm not allowed to use a lot of the standard theorems about homeomorphisms from topology.

To be clear, the continuous map needs to be from the square to the closed disc.

Comment: When you say "continuous map between": do you want it to be continuous bijection with continuous inverse?

Comment: But in any case, I think the answer to your question is "no", or that the easiest way is probably just to give an explicit construction.

Comment: @WillieWong No, just a simple continuous map. Homeomorphism isn't required in this case. I can't come up with an explicit construction through the tools available to me. I know how to construct a continuous function between the circle and the square, but I'm not sure how to extend that or if there is any explicit reason why such a continuous map cannot exist.

Comment: @WillieWong I have made an edit to my question which should help to clarify the issue.

Comment: Why are you interested in showing it without explicitly constructing a map? If you're only looking for an intuitive proof, it should be pretty clear that you can continuously bend a square to a circle.

Comment: @Besfort I just thought it would be easier to do it that way. I'm looking for guidance on a rigorous proof, not an intuitive proof.

Comment: There might be some way, although I would say it is unlikely. If you want a hint on how to construct an explicit map, it might be easier to think about it in terms of “layers”, i.e. think about the square as consisting of smaller squares centered at the center of the initial square with side length ranging from 0 to 1 and figure out where you’ll map each such square in the circle (it shall be helpful to also think of the circle in terms of layers in a similar way).

Comment: Do you require the map to be a surjection? If not, just subtracting $(1/2,1/2)$ would do.

Comment: @WillieWong No, a surjection is not required.

Comment: Actually: since you have the disc of radius 2: even the identity map is a continuous function from your unit square to the disc.